# Testing Typescript Generated Classes with node.js, Mocha and mocha-jsdom?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, jsdom

I would like to run unit tests from bash to test my Typescript generated Javascript classes using mocha and mocha-jsdom.  I'm using mocha-jsdom because I want to emulate the dom in my tests but run unit tests from bash.

I've seen a few examples where they use the frontend testing framework for mocha in a browser, but I haven't seen any where they are run from bash.

It appears that I am unable to include the Javascript classes generated from Typescript in my mocha unit tests.

```
var jsdom = require('../../index'); 
require('../../src/js/acct/AccountManager.js');

describe('GenerateHTML', function() {
  describe('#generateHTML()', function() {

    jsdom()

    it('should generate a table', function() {
        var vahm = new VerticalAccountHTMLManager(document, "testId");

        expect($("#testId")[0]).eql("table");   
    }); 
  });
});
```

Is there any way to import the functions that create the classes into the mocha unit test while still running it from bash?

Comment: two questions: why do you use TypeScript but do you test the generated JavaScript instead of TypeScript directly? And what about set up a nodejs application triggered by a bash file in order to execute the tests?

Comment: @quirimmo "Who do you use TypeScript but do the test with the generated Javascript instead of the TypeScript directly?"  Because I didn't know it was an option.

"And what about setting up a node js application triggered by a bash file (shell script) in order to execute the tests?"  I just wanted to run my tests.

Comment: good point :D Providing an answer with few code and examples that can be useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's start from executing the test. 
For executing the tests you have several options:

- Use `karma`. Karma is a JavaScript test runner. Actually you specify inside a `karma.config.js` file all the tests you want to execute, and it will execute all your tests. You have also a `watch` functionality which allows you to execute the test every time you make changes to your code
- Use node.js. Inside the script property of your `package.json` file, you specify the command `test` and you associate to that script the command in order to execute mocha against all your tests. Then you can run the test just typing `npm test`
- If you want to use a bash, my suggestion is to use it in order to trigger the npm test command or the karma command. That's the easiest way you can use for starting tests through bash. You can also setup a .bat file on Win which runs your tests always through the npm/karma commands
- Use a task runner as `Gulp`, `Grunt` etc... You can specify a task where you trigger your tests and then run the task providing for example the command `gulp mytask`

My suggestion is to use node.js directly at the moment. It makes things easier.

About TypeScript, you can directly use mocha with TypeScrit, no need of JavaScript. I suggest you to integrate mocha with chai, chai-as-promised and sinon. Chai is an assertion library. Chai-as-promised allows you to test promises and sinon to test functions and methods.

This is an example of `package.json` with the test command I was saying above:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "find ./src -name '*spec.ts' | xargs mocha -r ts-node/register"
}
```

With this line, you will execute all the files which end for `*spec.ts`.
The ts-node is a really useful node plugin which allows you to run ts directly through the command `ts-node myfile.ts`

About the dependencies to include in your `package.json` here a useful list:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "^3.5.0",
        "@types/chai-as-promised": "^0.0.30",
        "@types/mocha": "^2.2.40",
        "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
        "@types/sinon": "^2.1.2",
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
        "husky": "^0.13.3",
        "mocha": "^3.2.0",
        "sinon": "^2.1.0",
        "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
        "typings": "^2.1.1"
}
```

About how to integrate mocha inside your tests, here a declaration of a spec file that you can use as patter:

```
// imports of testing libraries 
import * as mocha from 'mocha';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import sinon = require('sinon');
// import of the source files to be tested
import Main from './Main'; // an example

// testing inits
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;
const should = chai.should();
```

You can try to take a look to this repo. There is a really simple project with TypeScript and all the testing libraries I said above. It's still in progress and I didn't have time to finish it yet, so also the main README.md is not updated. 
But if you clone the project or download the source, you can have a really panoramic of all the things I was saying above and an illustration of all the methods you can use inside your tests:

https://github.com/quirimmo/testing-typescript-mocha-chai-sinon

Hope this help! for any query let me know!