# Error: "jQuery requires a window with a document" with mocha and typescript?

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings

I have some typescript mocha unit tests that I'm running; I have successfully imported jquery, but I get an error:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';  // or maybe this should be in beforeEach() ?

...
it('should append a div', function() {
   $("body").append("div");  // ERROR: Causes "jQuery requires a window with a document"

});
```

I read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358015/error-jquery-requires-a-window-with-a-document) where the solution in node.js was:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);
```

but I tried to use `typings` to install `jsdom` and I get a different error which indicates that I'm not using the correct source...

```
$ typings search jsdom
NAME   SOURCE    HOMEPAGE                         DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED
jsdom  dt        https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom              2        2017-02-13T06:16:22.000Z


$ typings install jsdom
typings ERR! message Unable to find "jsdom" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "jsdom" for 1 other source: "dt"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/jsdom/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
typings ERR!
typings ERR! cwd /home/accounting/Documents/dev/anki-accounting-unit-tests
typings ERR! system Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
typings ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "jsdom"
typings ERR! node -v v4.2.6
typings ERR! typings -v 2.1.1
typings ERR!
typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

Also it appears that the author has dropped [node.js in favor of io.js](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md#400)

Should I be using something else, other than jsdom?

Comment: My experience is that JQuery isn't Node testing friend. I was trying it with JSDom, without success. Maybe new headless Chrome testing would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077455/testing-typescript-generated-classes-with-node-js-mocha-and-mocha-jsdom).

Failed to state in my question that I am using the following versions:

- node.js v4.2.6
- typings 2.1.1
- npm 3.5.2
- jquery ^3.2.1
- jdom ^3.1.2
- @types/jsdom ^2.0.30

Did the following (please let me know if it is not elegant)

```
// ...chai and mocha imports...
import * as jsdom from 'jsdom';
import * as jq from 'jquery';

// Import code to test...
import MeCode from './pirates/MeCode';
// ..

// testing inits
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;
const should = chai.should();

let mc,$ = null;
let someId = "yarId";

describe('Main Hooks', () => {
    // ..
    beforeEach(function() {
       // Initialize jQuery with a DOM it can work on....
       $ = jq(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow);

       // Initialize the object I'm testing...
       mc = new MeCode($, someId);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
       // clean up
       // ...
    });
    // ..

    it('should generate html', function() {
       ($("#" + someId).length).should.be.equal(1);
    });
});
```